# Wikipedia.section returns a None

Tags: python, python-3.x, wikipedia

The `wikipedia` package for python is able to retrieve sections from a wikipedia page. You can extract a list of sections and use elements from that list to retrieve the content of that section. I have been using it for many pages and came across one page which returns a `None` for one particular section:

```
import wikipedia

wikipedia.set_lang("nl")
page = wikipedia.page("Samenstelling_Tweede_Kamer_1875-1879")

secs = page.sections         #Get a complete list of the page's sections
print(page.section(secs[1])) #returns the section
print(page.section(secs[2])) #doesn't work, returns a None
```

I have checked the wikipedia page source and haven't found anything strange

**note**: I have installed the `wikipedia` package as follow:

```
pip3 install git+https://github.com/lucasdnd/Wikipedia.git
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by the response of the following 2 queries:

```
https://nl.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&prop=sections&page=Samenstelling_Tweede_Kamer_1875-1879&format=json
https://nl.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?explaintext=&rvprop=ids&titles=Samenstelling_Tweede_Kamer_1875-1879&prop=extracts|revisions&action=query&format=json
```

The section that doesn't work appears to have a double space. This double space gets removed only in the second query:

```
Conservatief-Katholiek  (14 zetels)
Conservatief-Katholiek (14 zetels)
```

This causes the issue in the wikipedia python module. I have [reported](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T185472) this issue on the wikimedia issue page.

Answer (score 0):

The `.section()` method in that package looks for a section heading formatted as follows:

```
section = u"== {} ==".format(section_title)
```

Note the spaces on each side of the title.  But the page you're looking at doesn't have those spaces for most of its sections: `==Gekozen bij de verkiezingen van 8 juni 1875==` for example.  This looks like a bug in the package to me, as I see no reason to expect that sections will be formatted that precisely.

Comment: I have looked at several pages in several languages and havn't seen any spaces at all in section titles.

Comment: So this cannot be the reason, because the method works fine for the first section which do not have spaces too.